# Back to previous ViewController from class func

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I try to close and go back to previous viewController using:

```
class func closeViewController()
{
    presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

But this gives me a compilation error.

if i remove the "class" identifyer it works, but i need this function to be class function

Comment: Why do you need it to be a class function?

Comment: I am displaying an ad and from the ad dismiss callback i want to close the containing ViewController. the ad callback is received from other class

Answer (score 4):

Just because you receive a callback from another class doesn't mean that you need your `closeViewController` method to be a class method. It's likely that it should not be a class method.

presentingViewController is an instance method of UIViewController. There is an implied "self" at the beginning:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(
  true, completion: nil)
```

However, a class method is performed on the class, not an instance, so self is the class, not an instance.

If you really do need it to be a class method for some reason, you will need to pass in either the current view controller or the presenting view controller as a parameter to the method.

```
class func closeViewController(theModal: UIViewController)
{
  theModal.dismissViewControllerAnimated(
    true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, waybe you can direct me how to keep a referance to the current ViewController. BTW the closeViewController is inside the current running ViewController class

Comment: But you made it a class method. That means it is a method that runs on the entire class, not an instance of the class, and thus it does not have access to any particular instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That won't work because the OPs method is a class method. You can't invoke instance methods on self from a class method.